# How we can define Enter and Exit block to conenct the main flowchart in any logic?

Tags: anylogic, exit, exit-code, enter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my7RJ.jpg)
How we can connect these two flowcharts together?
in order to complete the main flowchart we want to insert the flowchart which starts by Enter and finishes by Exit.
we need the code to insert in the action part of these blocks.

Answer (score 0):

In the "on exit" code of an `Exit` block, you can write `myEnterBlock.take(agent);`. This will send agents from the exit to the enter.

Also always check the help on blocks you struggle with: https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/process-modeling-library/exit.html#exit This one even has a detailed video for you :)